# Joomla - Modifying default category list view (through overrides?)

Tags: joomla, overriding, categories

I'm building a site for a friend and I should state that this is not what I'm doing for living. I just started working with Joomla a few days ago.

Everything is good so far, except I'm stuck at one point.

This is a site for a construction company and I need to create articles for on-going and completed projects. I will create an article for each project and each article will belong to a category, 'Completed' and 'On-Going', respectfully.

I plan to create menu links for 'Completed' and 'On-Going' categories in main menu. I also want to present a thumbnail of the article on the category list. Problem is, standard look of the category list is kinda ugly, and I have no idea how to change it. I'm using a template named PixelDot, but it does not seem to do any good for my problem.

During my research, I stumbled upon concepts 'Layout Overrides' and 'Alternative Layouts'. I have basic html and css knowledge, also some PHP, but I am totally lost on which file(s) to modify. I also need a little help on get the entry text picture as a thumbnail on the category list (this is the list where you see 'articles' aka projects which belongs to the category (completed or on-going), when you clicked on relevant menu button)

Any help will be highly appreciated. My Joomla version is 3.4.1. (which I believe most up-to-date version as today)

I'm sometimes making it more complex while I try to make things detailed and clear, I hope this is not one of those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest using tags rather than categories to manage this. Tags are much better suited for temporary labelling or dividing into groups.

Second, go to the template manager, template view for your template.
Go to the create over ride tab and select the view that you want to override (i.e. tagged items).
This will automatically copy all the files to the correct location in your template.
At that point you can play around with the layouts to your heart's content.
Also ... some pieces of the layout you may want to override may not be in the traditional layout but may be in a jlayout.  You can do the same thing with them. THis is all documented in the docs.joomla.org site as well as around the web.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am in the overrides section, but it is a little confusing.

- There is html/com_content/categories and then html/com_content/category. Which is the one I should be modifying? 
- there are files named default.php, default_articles.php, default_children.php, blog.php, blog_children.php etc. Are these follows to a naming convention or just entirely up to the template creator? I looked up to the documentation but could not find any info about it :(
Last, but not least, how can I echo the address of the entry picture of the article? I could not find it in docs too.

Comment: You really need to read hte documentation but categorIES is for a list of categories, category is for a list of items in a category. Yes as is obvious if you read the code default is the base file and it includes (if you want) the subtemplates that start with default_. Likewise blog and the subtemplates which begin with blog_.  There is a large amount of documentation about alternate layouts both on the docs site and around the web.  As I said you are better off using tags than categories for this purpose but the same thing will apply.

Answer (score 0):

I also would do this with Tags.  One reason is, assuming you are using SEF URLS, that the projects article pages will have a unique URL.  If you move a project's article from "on-going" to "completed" then you may be changing that SEF url.  This will cause your search engine ranking for that page to be lost.

I would tag each article "on-going", "completed", etc and then create a menu item to display only that specific tag.  The project's article would stay in its original category, that could be my project type, project location, etc; which also will increase the SEO for that given project's article.